# Why is hg commit creating a new head?

Tags: mercurial

I've added a bunch of files to my Mercurial repository, and when I now do `hg commit -m "Bunch of new files"` I get a message saying `Created new head`. I can't understand why this might be, unless my repository has somehow got corrupted. It's a pretty simple repo, with no branches, just default. I don't want to create a new head. Is there a way of forcing a commit which doesn't create a new head? (This is new behaviour, incidentally - I've been working with the repo for a couple of years, pushing changes to Bitbucket).

Answer (score 3):

What probably happened is something like this...

Your starting point was a repo that had a few changesets:

```
a-b-c-*
```

(`*` is your local working folder - not a commit)

Later on, you did an `hg pull` which made your repo look like this:

```
a-b-c-d-e
    \
     *
```

because someone else had committed `d` & `e` in the meantime.

Then later when you `hg commit`, you get this:

```
a-b-c-d-e
    \
     f-*
```

And `f` is your new head. You can also think of `f` as the tip of an anonymous branch.

So this is just how Mercurial works (and its actually a very useful feature, when you want it).

At this point, you can either `hg merge` `e` and `f`, yielding:

```
a-b-c-d-e
    \    \ 
     f-----g-*
```

or you could `hg rebase` `f` onto `e`, to get:

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-*
```

(You can't really `rebase` the other way - to put `d` and `e` onto `f`, because they are 'public' having been pushed by someone else already.)

Both `merge` & `rebase` are fine to use and its a bit subjective which is "better". Merging preserves the actual history of what happened more closely, but also makes the history harder to follow.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand why this might be

New head (aka "anonymous branches") may appear in just one case: then parent of this new commit isn't HEAD at the moment of commit (HEAD of active branch, even if it's "default"). For "why not HEAD" can be at least two possible reasons:

- active changeset wasn't head in working dir at start
- some (new) changesets were pulled from upstream in the middle

BTW: AFAICR, "Creating new head" is error on push, not on local commit.

> I don't want to create a new head. Is there a way of forcing a commit which doesn't create a new head?

Rebase diverged history in local repository before push to correct destination in order to eliminate branchpoint

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can help me, please, with what 'Rebase diverged history in local repository before push to correct destination in order to eliminate branchpoint' means. Yes, I thought the creating new head issue was from 'hg push' but it's definitely occurring on 'hg commit'.

Comment: Actually, I'm beginning to think this is repository corruption. I may have to clone and rebuild somehow.

Comment: @JohnMoore it definitely does not sound like corruption to me. "Rebase" is an HG command to move changesets around. The more common approach is to merge your new head with the pre-existing head. Either will work, although rebase will produce a nicer looking graph of changeset history.

Comment: Used merge in the end, now all is OK.